# How to correct for unequal sample size per group in neg. binomial regression

Tags: biostatistics, negative-binomial-distribution, small-sample

My data contains information on the time, location, and present conditions of a fish catch. The problem we often have in the field is that not all locations can be consistently visited every time. Additionally, some unique areas are larger, so they get sampled more than others.

If I'm modeling the count of one species (pred_count) based on the count of a prey species (prey_count), and other factors, with a negative binomial model, do I need to correct my model (in R) for the fact that one basin (called Zone = "West") maybe overrepresented in my analysis because it's the largest? How do I identify if this characteristic is causing problems in my results? Or, is the fact that there are a total of zero counts in the smallest location the most likely cause for skewed results, more so than any problems with sample size? *I changed the reference level of Zone to avoid any convergence issues this causes.

```r
head(df) *Manually exaggerated (all Zones 
   have at least 6 sites/year)
         Site     Zone     prey_count     pred_count  Area_searched  Year
    1    1      Whipray    2              0           383.9854       2009
    2    1         West    38             0           382.2256       2009
    3    2         West    10             0           382.2256       2009
    3    3         West     1             7           382.2256       2009
    3    4         West    22             0           382.2256       2009
    4    1    Crocodile    25             0           408.3697       2009
    5    1       Rankin    2              0           165.5196       2009
    6    1      Whipray    6              1           266.7000       2010
```

Distribution of sites visited by year and location:

```r
table(x$Zone, x$Year)
           
            2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020 2021
  Crocodile   13   17   17   19   21   17   18   21   20   24   27   17   20
  Rankin       8   11   14   12   14   12   12   12   14   18   17   12   13
  West        10   11   13   32   34   29   29   35   35   43   41   29   30
  Whipray      6   12   13   10   13   11   12   13   14   18   18   12   14
```

Area_searched = area the net covered at each site in a basin (region of water called "Zone")

```r
collect <- within(collect, Zone <- 
   relevel(Zone, ref = 2)) 
   # Reference level change    

nb <- glmer.nb(pred_count ~  poly(Year, 3) + 
       I(prey_count/Area_searched) + Zone + 
       offset(log(Area_towed)) + (1 | site), 
       data=collect)
```

Does the added random effect of Site help?: `+ (1 | site)`?

```r
car::Anova(nb, type = 3)
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type III Wald 
  chisquare tests)

Response: pred_count
                             Chisq   Df Pr(>Chisq)    
(Intercept)                 615.6824  1  < 2.2e-16 ***
poly(Year, 3)                21.7589  3  7.322e-05 ***
I(prey_count/Area_searched)   4.4105  1    0.03572 *  
Zone                         61.0875  3  3.443e-13 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>  summary(nb)
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: Negative Binomial(0.1686)  ( log )
Formula: pred_count ~ poly(Year, 3) + 
 I(prey_count/Area_searched) + 
 offset(log(Area_searched)) + Zone + 
 (1 | Site)
   Data: collect

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  1038.5   1087.1   -509.2   1018.5      947 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.4106 -0.3370 -0.1972 -0.0816 16.2194 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 value  (Intercept) 0.04921  0.2218  
Number of obs: 957, groups:  value, 12

Fixed effects:
                           Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                -7.38392    0.29758 -24.813  < 2e-16 ***
poly(Year, 3)1             11.74276    4.12876   2.844 0.004453 ** 
poly(Year, 3)2             -2.99638    3.96601  -0.756 0.449940    
poly(Year, 3)3            -12.90174    3.94129  -3.273 0.001062 ** 
I(carid_count/Area_searched)   0.20522    0.09772   2.100 0.035718 *  
ZoneCrocodile              -3.60828    0.79567  -4.535 5.76e-06 ***
ZoneWest                    0.90122    0.35400   2.546 0.010903 *  
ZoneWhipray                -1.93454    0.54382  -3.557 0.000375 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) p(Y,3)1 p(Y,3)2 p(Y,3)3 I(_/A_ ZnCrcd ZonWst
poly(Yr,3)1 -0.213                                             
poly(Yr,3)2 -0.036 -0.028                                      
poly(Yr,3)3  0.101  0.059  -0.185                              
I(crd_c/A_) -0.029  0.018   0.093  -0.188                      
ZoneCrocodl -0.355  0.029   0.022   0.013   0.018              
ZoneWest    -0.825  0.137   0.058  -0.094  -0.107  0.308       
ZoneWhipray -0.520  0.036   0.028   0.019   0.015  0.197  0.442
```

Comment: Under fixed effects: "I(carid_count/Area_searched)" should be "I(prey_count/Area_searched". Also, I think under Random effects, "value" should be "Site".

Comment: Count totals by location: (Rankin=52, Crocodile=2, West=267, Whipray=7)